# Can someone explain this proof of the remainder of the quotient?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Theorem (uniqueness of quotients and remains): For $a$ and $ b > 0 $ of natural numbers, there is only one pair of natural numbers $(k, r)$ with $ r < b$ such that $a = k*b + r$.

Proof. Let us first show that such a pair exists. Choose $k$ such that $k*b \leq a <(k +1) * b$. It is always possible to find such a natural number k. We then have $a = k * b + r$ with $r < b$ since $ r = a - k * b <(k + 1) * b - k * b = b$.

---

This isn't the full proof if you're wondering. I have trouble understanding what it means.

**1.Why do we choose a $k$ between $k*b \leq a <(k +1) * b$ ?**

**2.Why it's always possible to find such a natural number $k$?**

**I do not understand what is going on here $ r = a - k * b <(k + 1) * b - k * b = b$.**

**3.Why do we subtracte $k*b$ from both sides?**

**4.Why do we use the right side at all?**

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the 2nd "why". The answer to all other whys is that we want to prove the theorem. That's why we do all these manipulations.

**2.Why it's always possible to find such a natural number $k$?**

I think it follows from the Axiom of Archimedes that such $k$ exists.

**Axiom of Archimedes**: Given any real number $x$, there is an integer $n$ such that $x<n$.

But this is rather formal. Maybe it's better to think about it this way: if you're given $a$ and you start adding $b+b+b+...$ eventually you will surpass your number $a$. Denote the minimal such sum of $b$s as M. Then of course M is a multiple of b. This means we can write $M=(k+1)b$ for some integer $k>=0$. Now... the "previous multiple" of $b$ (the one right before M) will then be $N=kb$ but it will already be $ \leq a $. And that's all. Now you have: $kb \leq a \lt (k+1)b$.